# Mocha Testing Getting "getting 500 Unexpected JSON o in JSON at position 1" when I try to pass json object for test

Tags: node.js, json, unit-testing, mocha.js

**Am getting 500 Unexpected JSON o in JSON at position 1.**

1. I have tried removing quotes from json keys, it works on postman but fails in mocha.
2. Tried using JSON.stringify to send data too, some issue with parsing json data.
3. Tried using mocha .type('json') to but had no results.
   My mocha test is as follows:-

```
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../../../../index');
const httpStatus = require('http-status');
const User = require('../../../models/auth/user.model');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const appModel = require('../../../models/app/apps.model');
const RefreshToken = require('../../../models/auth/refreshToken.model');

describe('API', async () => {
    let appParam;
    let validApiParam;
    let userAccessToken;
    let Ace;

    const password = '123456';

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const passwordHashed = await bcrypt.hash(password, 1);
    Ace = {
      email: 'myMail@gmail.com',
      password: passwordHashed,
      name: 'ace',
      role: 'user',
    };

    await User.deleteMany({});
    await appModel.deleteMany({});
    await RefreshToken.deleteMany({});
    await User.insertMany([Ace]);
    Ace = await User.findOne({ name: Ace.name }).exec();

    appParam = {
      name: 'aegis project',
      appDescription: 'It is authentication app',
      userId: Ace._id.toString(),
    };

    appParam = await appModel.create(appParam);

    validApiParam = {
      name: 'validNewApi',
      url: 'testurl',
      methodName: 'POST',
      apiType: 2,
      requestParameter: {
        'email': 'eve.holt@reqres.in',
        'password': 'cityslicka',
    },
    responseParameter: {
      'version': '1',
      'user': {
          'id': 123,
      },
  },
    userIdKeyPath: 'user.id',
    serviceProvider: 'axios',
    userId: Ace._id.toString(),
    appId: appParam._id.toString(),

  };
    Ace.password = password;
    userAccessToken = (await User.findAndGenerateToken(Ace)).accessToken;
  });

  describe('POST /apiRegistration/save-login-api/save-login-api', () => {
    it('should create a new login Api', () => {
      return request(app)
        .post('/apiRegistration/save-login-api/save-login-api')
        .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${userAccessToken}`)
        .send(JSON.stringify(validApiParam))
        .expect(httpStatus.CREATED)
        .then(() => {
        });
    });
});
});
```

Any suggestions provided would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried removing `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: yeah i tried but it didnt work. am getting the same error above. Api works in postman but does not in mocha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution I was parsing already JSON formatted request parameters in my logic resulting in this error.